# Custom Metadata value in formula - access values based on field label or record data?

Tags: apex, formula, email-template, custom-metadata

According to this article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_validation_rules.htm&type=5) we can use Custom Metadata in a formula now. What I'd like to know is how extract the value based on the field label? This article seems to suggest we can only use the field name, not a specific record of the metadata (if there is more than one record).

My Custom Metadata needs to contain different text data to be used based on some criteria ie 'if fieldx = 'ABC' use the text value from the field 'Next Steps' where label = 'Funds Due', else use text from where label = 'Default'. I want to use this for an email template. 
This is my Custom Metadata, with currently only the 1 custom field for the text.

[image]

This is in my records (Manage *metadataRecordNameFields*)

[image]

Should I instead be creating multiple fields (ie 'Next Steps Default', 'Option1', 'Option2'...)and have only 1 record, or should I have multiple records where the field label identifies the value in 'Next Steps' (as I have now)?

If I try and create a formula field, my 'Next Steps' field does not show up - why not? I have set the Field Usage to 'Public'.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What the article says is to use Name instead of label. Name behaves like the "API" key of a CMTDT record and thus it should be unique and is not expected to change. Instead, the Label is for display purposes, contains spaces and may not be unique.

In summary, in your screenshot, you want to use value contained in the field labeled `Custom Metadata Record Name`, not `Label`

If your CMTDT records look like this:

```
Name|Label|Next Steps
Def|Default|This is my default text
Funds_Due|Funds Due|This is my funds due text
```

In your formula you should use

```
$CustomMetadata.MyCustomMetadata__mdt.Funds_Due.NextSteps__c
```

instead of

```
$CustomMetadata.MyCustomMetadata__mdt.Funds Due.NextSteps__c
```

Comment: Sebastian, if I try and create the formula field, my Next Steps field doesn't come up for selection (I edited my question to add this) - any idea why?

Comment: Very likely because it is Long Text

Comment: Ok, so does this mean then my idea of using metadata for different paragraphs is not viable?

Comment: I am almost sure it works as long as you use the regular text(255) type. Test it by creating a regular  text field and seeing if that one appears on your list.